# How detect modem connected to the USB of system through commands in linux

Tags: modem, cdma

I going to develop device driver for CDMA modem. Before going to develop device driver first of all i want to find whether my modem is connected or not, if connected i want to detect the name of the device present in the /dev directory so that i can open that device file and send AT commands to the modem.How can i detect my modem using commands please help me

Answer (score 0):

Look at the output of `dmesg` after connecting the USB device. Further you can use `wvdial` to dial your modem.